# convert c function with varargs in ellipsis style to python equivalent using ctypes

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, variadic-functions, ellipsis

I have a c function with the following signautre

func(enum_type level, const char* function, const int line, const char* file, const char* msg, ...)

What would be the equivalent param types that need to be passed in the ctypes decorator call?

I tried something like this

@CFUNCTYPE(None, level, POINTER(c_char), c_int, POINTER(c_char), POINTER(c_char),"...")

since "..." is not a ctypes type not sure how to handle this

Answer (score 2):

Don't specify anything for `...`. `ctypes` allows extra parameters, but you may have to hint how to marshal the parameters correctly.  Without specific `argtypes`, `ctypes` will assume conversion to `c_int` for `int` parameters, `c_char_p` for `bytes`, `c_wchar_p` for `str` and either fail or do the wrong thing for other parameters.  Do the conversion manually if needed.  Example:

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('msvcrt')                 # For printf/wprintf on Windows
dll.wprintf.argtypes = ct.c_wchar_p,    # int wprintf(const wchar_t*, ...)
dll.wprintf.restype = ct.c_int
dll.printf.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,      # int printf(const char*, ...)
dll.printf.restype = ct.c_int

dll.wprintf("%s, %d, %lf\n", "hello", 123, ct.c_double(3.14))
handle = 0x123456789 # >32-bit.  Pointers are 64-bit on my system.
dll.wprintf("%p\n", ct.c_void_p(handle))
dll.printf(b"%s, %s!\n", b'Hello', b'world')
```

Output:

```
hello, 123, 3.140000
0000000123456789
Hello, world!
```

If you remove the `ct.c_double()` or `ct.c_void_p` conversions, `ctypes` complains it doesn't know how to marshal the `float`, and complains that the `int` is too big since it is larger than a `c_int` can hold.